# How to delete only specific word with @ like "Whats App" using KEY_DEL programmatically in android

Tags: java, android-layout

This is my code and I want to delete a word which come from RecyclerView using @

For Example;

I want to delete @Tapan whole word only;

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
     if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){  

     //here how can I delete whole word with @ value

}
return false;       
    }
});
```

Comment: You can get Text from edittext and using replace method delete word.

Comment: Can you give me example code?

Comment: Please check my edited answer !!

Comment: Are you get your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this example:

```
      String str="@Hello!!! Ple@ase try the @Example for a @solution";
    //Split by space
    String arrStr[]=str.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String>arrList=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<arrStr.length;i++)
    {
        //check first character of string
        if(arrStr[i].charAt(0)=='@')
        {
            //if start with @ remove
           arrList.remove(arrStr[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            arrList.add(arrStr[i]);
        }
    }
    Iterator it=arrList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.print(it.next()+" ");
    }
```

When you input `**@Hello!!! Ple@ase try the @Example for a @solution**` into this example code, you'll get `**Ple@ase try the for a**`
 as output.

Comment: No I dont want to remove only @ from word...I want to delete whole which is with @ like whats app group chat like @Tapan,@Ashok remove whole word with @

Answer (score 1):

For example your string is like this.

```
    String name = "Hello @tapan this is sample string @test";

    String finalSentence = "";
    String[] wordsArray = name.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
        if (wordsArray[i].charAt(0) == '@') {
            continue;
        }else{
            finalSentence += wordsArray[i] + " ";
        }
    }
```

*finalSentence* is your output.

Hope this may help.